# Publishing my screen and camera at same time using Janus WebRTC Gateway

Tags: screensharing, janus

the following codes is my screen sharing stuff and which works fine.
But i also want to publish my local camera when i share my screen, is it possible, if yes how can i do it ?

Publish feed code.

```
function publishOwnFeed(useAudio, isScreenSharing) {
    let media = null;
    if (isScreenSharing) {
        media = {
            video: "screen",
            audioRecv: false,
            videoRecv: false,
            audioSend: useAudio,
            videoSend: true
        };
    } else {
        media = {
            audioRecv: false,
            videoRecv: false,
            audioSend: useAudio,
            videoSend: true
        };
    }
    // Publish our stream
    handler.createOffer({
        // Add data:true here if you want to publish datachannels as well
        media: media, // Publishers are sendonly
        // If you want to test simulcasting (Chrome and Firefox only), then
        // pass a ?simulcast=true when opening this demo page: it will turn
        // the following 'simulcast' property to pass to janus.js to true
        simulcast: doSimulcast,
        simulcast2: doSimulcast2,
        success: function(jsep) {
            Janus.debug("Got publisher SDP!", jsep);
            let publish = { request: "configure", audio: useAudio, video: true };
            if (acodec)
                publish["audiocodec"] = acodec;
            if (vcodec)
                publish["videocodec"] = vcodec;
            handler.send({ message: publish, jsep: jsep });
        },
        error: function(error) {
            Janus.error("WebRTC error:", error);
            toggleElement(shareScreen);
            if (useAudio) {
                 publishOwnFeed(false);
            } else {
                Toastnotify.create({
                    text: "WebRTC error... " + error.message,
                    type: 'danger',
                    important: false
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Start screenshare code.

```
function startScreenShare() {
    unpublishOwnFeed();
    setTimeout(function(){
        publishOwnFeed(false, true);  // publish my screen whihout audio
    }, 800);
    // setTimeout(function(){
    //  publishOwnFeed(false, false); // this is not work. (publish my camera whitout audio to others to just see me)
    // }, 800);
}
```

Stop screenshare code.

```
function stopScreenShare() {
    unpublishOwnFeed();
    setTimeout(function(){
        publishOwnFeed(true, false);
    }, 800);
    toggleElement(shareScreen);
}
```

i really appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks Kimberlee,
after trying I was able to add my own video to other participants.
by the way, the code is tested only on my local computer, it has not been tested online yet.
i am sharing this code maybe it can help someone. :)

```
let screenHandler = null;

function unpublishMyCameraForScreenShare() {
    // Unpublish our stream
    let unpublish = { request: "unpublish" };
    screenHandler.send({ message: unpublish });
}
function startScreenShare() {
    unpublishOwnFeed();
    setTimeout(function(){
        publishOwnFeed(false, true);  // publish my screen whihout audio
    }, 800);

    janus.attach({
        plugin: "janus.plugin.videoroom",
        opaqueId: opaqueId,
        success: function(pluginHandle) {
            screenHandler = pluginHandle;
            Janus.log(":: Screen handler attached! (" + screenHandler.getPlugin() + ", id=" + screenHandler.getId() + ")");

            let register = {
                request: "join",
                room: parseInt(roomId),
                ptype: "publisher",
                display: currentUserName
            };
            screenHandler.send({ message: register });

            // janus.destroy();
        },
        error: function(error) {
            Janus.error("  -- Error attaching plugin...", error);
        },
        consentDialog: function(on) {
            // Janus.debug("Consent dialog should be " + (on ? "on" : "off") + " now");
            if (on) {
                // open screen
            } else {
                // close screen
            }
        },
        iceState: function(state) {
            Janus.log("ICE state changed to " + state);
        },
        mediaState: function(medium, on) {
            Janus.log("Janus " + (on ? "started" : "stopped") + " receiving our " + medium);
        },
        webrtcState: function(on) {
            // bağlantı durumu
            Janus.log("Janus says our WebRTC PeerConnection is " + (on ? "up" : "down") + " now");
            if (!on)
                return;
        },
        onmessage: function(msg, jsep) {
            Janus.debug(" ::: Screen handler got a message (publisher) :::", msg);
            console.log(msg);

            let event = msg["videoroom"];
            Janus.debug("Event: " + event);
            if (! event) {
                return;
            }
            if (event === "joined") {
                // Publisher/manager created, negotiate WebRTC and attach to existing feeds, if any
                Janus.log("Successfully joined room " + msg["room"] + " with ID " + msg["id"]);
                
                // video conference
                publishMyCameraForScreenShare();

            } else if (event === "destroyed") {
                // // The room has been destroyed
                Janus.warn("The room has been destroyed!");
            }
        },
        onlocalstream: function(stream) {
            Janus.debug(" ::: ScreenHandler got a local stream :::", stream);
        },
        onremotestream: function(stream) {
            // The publisher stream is sendonly, we don't expect anything here
        },
        oncleanup: function() {
            Janus.log(" ::: Screen handler got a cleanup notification: we are unpublished now :::");
        }
    });
}
function stopScreenShare() {
    unpublishOwnFeed();
    unpublishMyCameraForScreenShare();
    setTimeout(function(){
        publishOwnFeed(true, false);
    }, 800);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Janus, but I've worked with other WebRTC libraries (like [Daily](https://www.daily.co/)) and know this is possible. Here is the pseudocode for how I would do that with any library:

- Start a call following the library's docs
- Get the person who started the call's local camera stream, with WebRTC directly or the library's help
- Insert that camera stream, when it starts, into an HTML element with a corresponding identifier

From looking at Janus briefly, this [video call demo](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway/blob/master/html/videocalltest.js) would be where I'd start to try to add the video stream. If there'd be a way to combine that with the [screen sharing demo](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway/blob/master/html/screensharingtest.js), that'd be ideal.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

idk wold be usefull or no, but if you want to publish few different video streams (screen and camera for example) same time, you have to attach few janus video-room plugins.
For subscribers it would be look like two different publishers with their own streams.